# Subresource Integrity and cross-origin data leaks

Tags: javascript, html, http, cross-domain

I'm reading about Subsource Integrity on Mozilla [[1]](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/subresource-integrity-in-firefox-43/). They analyse the code snippet below and write the following about it:

> The anonymous value means that the browser should omit any cookies or authentication that the user may have associated with the domain. **This prevents cross-origin data leaks, and also makes the request smaller.**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
integrity="sha384-R4/ztc4ZlRqWjqIuvf6RX5yb/v90qNGx6fS48N0tRxiGkqveZETq72KgDVJCp2TC"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I'm interested in why this prevents cross-origin data leaks [[2]](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/#cross-origin-data-leakage). Mozilla writes the following:

> **Attackers would attempt to load the resource with a known digest, and watch for load failures.** If the load fails, the attacker could surmise that the response didn’t match the hash and thereby gain some insight into its contents. This might reveal, for example, whether or not a user is logged into a particular service.

I understand how the `integrity` attribute can be used to reveal the contents of the resource. This seems interesting if the contents are client-dependent. However, I do not understand two things:

1. If it happens to be the case that a hacker is interested in the contents of a resource when the resource is loaded by a particular client, and the hacker can control the HTML and Javascript on this page. Then why would the hacker try to reveal the contents of said resource by using the integrity hash, why not just fetch the resources on the client and send the `responseText` to a malicious website straight away? Unless CORS prevents this, of course, but it seems like CORS blocks SRI just as much as other requests [[3]](https://www.srihash.org/)...
2. Mozilla seems to describe that website-owners need to set `crossorigin` to `anonymous` so that hackers can not "bruteforce" page info by brute-forcing hashes? If the hackers can control the `integrity` attribute on the page, they can control the `crossorigin` attribute too in most cases, so why does this matter?

Answer (score 0):

The situation you describe is different from what the authors of that documentation had in mind. The attacker may not be interested in the *exact* content of the response to an authenticated request triggered by a subresource load; instead, the attacker may simply want to determine, from a malicious origin, whether the victim is logged in to the target.

Imagine a case where the response to `GET`ting `https://example.com/1.js` depends on whether the request carries some authentication cookie (marked `SameSite=None; Secure` here, for simplicity):

```js
alert('authenticated');
```

or

```js
alert('anonymous');
```

The SHA-256 of `alert('anonymous');` (followed by a newline) is `a7c873e2f388c05f57d1245cfa0c20e4bf5b064677ba4f959c5dd53668590339`. The attacker could set up the following malicious page, which would function as a *login oracle*:

```
<script integrity="sha256-a7c873e2f388c05f57d1245cfa0c20e4bf5b064677ba4f959c5dd53668590339" 
        src="https://example.com/1.js"
        crossorigin="use-credentials"
        onerror="notifyAttackerVisitorIsLoggedInToExampleDotCom();">
```

When the victim visits the attacker's malicious page, two cases are possible:

- If the victim is *not* logged in `https://example.com`, the response to the subresource load contains `alert('anonymous');`, whose hash value matches the one specified in the attacker's `integrity` attribute. No error occurs.
- If the victim *is* logged in `https://example.com`, the response to the subresource load contains `alert('authenticated');`, whose hash value doesn't match the one specified in the attacker's `integrity` attribute. Therefore, an error occurs and the `onerror` event listener fires, notifying the attacker.

Comment: Hmmm, I realize now that I'm not answering the question... I'll come back to this later when I have more time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand your answer and it's definitely in the direction that I'm interested in, but it's indeed not yet an answer to my question. Thanks regardless, and I'm looking forward to your reply. Cheers!